express-async-handler and mongoose session
In few videos I followed, they recommend to use express-async-handler but I am still not clear on it. But more importantly, how can one use it with sessions?
const proc = = expressAsyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    const newUser = await Data.create(..)
    const newGroup = await Group.create(...)
     session.commitTransaction()
}

now I could have an error in group so the whole thing should be rolled back. My error handler is defined in my entry file index.ts as follows
app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Error Found')
})

so my question is...how can i do session abort?

The following post will try to address the second part of the question. Answer to the first part of this question has already been posted separately. It is a prerequisite to at least skim through it in order to proceed with this part.
Now handling errors in this question, the original code would need to be refactored. Please see the respective codes below.
The original code
const proc = = expressAsyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    const newUser = await Data.create(..)
    const newGroup = await Group.create(...)
     session.commitTransaction()
}

Refactored  - code using express-async-handler
const proc1 = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    try {
      const newUser = await Data.create('..');
      const newGroup = await Group.create('..');
      await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (error) {
      await session.abortTransaction();
      throw error;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  } finally {
    session.endSession();
  }
});

Alternatively, without using the NPM module express-async-handler and by following the manual way “catch and pass the error” as in server3.js, the following refactoring would be required.
Refactored - code using manual error handling
const proc2 = async (req, res, next) => { 
  try {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    try {
      const newUser = await Data.create('..');
      const newGroup = await Group.create('..');
      await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (error) {
      await session.abortTransaction();
      next(error);
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
    return;
  } finally {
    session.endSession();
  }
};

Notes:

The error handled in the above codes, would invoke the custom error handler defined in index.js. This is irrespective of the files in which these refactored codes are hosted. And this is the basic feature of Express  error handling mechanism.

Aborting a session is always done in catch blocks as shown in the codes. Please also note the placement commit and session ending statements as well.

The codes given above have not been tested.

For a full listing of tested codes handling a similar requirement, please refer to the post given under Links section.

For brevity, the types have been avoided from the refactored codes.


Links:

Abort transaction friendly way to update multiple documents in mongodb?


There are two sub questions in this post.

async error handling generally in express
handling errors specifically in mongoose transactions

The following post will try to address the first part of the question. The second sub question is addressed in another post, please see it as well.

async error handling generally in express

It may be useful to start discussing this matter - async error handling, under the background of the sync error handling.
Let us see the  code below, please note it is a sync middleware. Please also see below the test results. The error has been handled by express and written to both the server and client consoles. Please also note that the server is still running, it did not crash even after the error. This is what can be understood from this server.
server1.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const syncmiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  throw new Error('Error from sync code');
};

app.use(syncmiddleware);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

testing the server:
curl http://localhost:3000
server console : Error: Error from sync code…, server is still running, no crash.
client console :  Error: Error from async code…

Now we shall see the next code, which is an async middleware. Below the test results show the following
things.
At the server console, though the error has been written, the server has crashed.
At the client console, curl reported as an empty reply from the server.
server2.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const asyncmiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  throw new Error('Error from async code');
};

app.use(asyncmiddleware);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

testing the server:
curl http://localhost:3000
server console : Error: Error from sync code…[nodemon] app crashed
client console :  curl: (52) Empty reply from server…

Now the third code, this is again an async middleware, still the error has
been handled by the programmer or by the application code.
The test results are very same as that of the results from server1.js. It means the error in an async code has to be caught by the app code, and must pass it to express. The code try-catch block catches the error, and the code next(error) passes it to express. Rest is the same as that of a sync code case.
server3.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const asyncmiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    throw new Error('Error from async code');
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
    return;
  }
};

app.use(asyncmiddleware);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

testing the server:
curl http://localhost:3000
server console : Error: Error from sync code…, server is still running, no crash.
client console :  Error: Error from async code…

Now we have reached one of the main topics of the post, the express-async-handler. The below async
code uses the same. The test results are the same as that of server3.js. It handles the error from async code. However unlike server3.js, there is no extra code to handle the error. This is the advantage of using this npm module.
server4.js
const express = require('express');
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const app = express();

const asyncmiddleware = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    throw new Error('Error from async code');
});

app.use(asyncmiddleware);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

testing the server:
curl http://localhost:3000
server console : Error: Error from sync code…, server is still running, no crash.
client console :  Error: Error from async code…

The summary of the discussion:

server1.js

server3.js

server4.js


All the above three servers although have different kinds of codes - sync and async, it all handles the error and behaves in the same manner. However the implementation within each differs as below.

server1.js - sync code, express does handle the error automatically, no app code is required for it.

server3.js - async code, express does not handle the error, app code is required to handle the error.

server4.js - async code, the npm module - express-async-handler, handles the error, no app code is required for it.


Notes:

Express 4.x is the version used in the tests and documentation.
Express 5 handles async errors differently.
The default error handler in Express is at work in all the tests, a custom error handler avoided for the sake of brevity and focus.

Citation:

Error Handling
Handle exceptions properly

